# Google Sheets - Preserving Data after Importing Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-query

I work in an organization where we give people jobs across 3 of our programs. I am trying to create a spreadsheet that can have a master list of all of our participants and which program they are in (A, B, or C) and importing it to another tab in the same spreadsheet where their hours are tracked semi-monthly. We do intake constantly, so new entries are being added and hours are also being added constantly. We want to try to keep the master list alphabetized so it is easier to enter hours.

Here is the problem I am facing. Assuming our destination sheet has names imported and hours entered previously, we run into an issue when adding a new participant in the master sheet and sorting alphabetically- the hours entered for the previously entered participants in the destination sheet do not stick after the sort.

I understand why I am facing this problem, I am just unsure how to fix it. Any advice is appreciated. Please see below for a sample spreadsheet. Note that the numbers are just a placeholder for people's names.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11fNTLzJtAvo3WQNlSadvO0j8eIiCf8QeOThxwaaeS2Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to have everyone use *one and the same* tab in the spreadsheet. They can view just their "own" rows by using [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to decide which rows to show at a time. This feature lets multiple simultaneous users sort, filter and edit the sheet without disturbing each other.

For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.